# FullCalendar is blank when having to be redrawn from empty data

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've been trying to debug this issue for a good couple days now, but have not gotten anywhere.

I am using FullCalendar with the latest Fiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/46tnzj72/19/)

My dataset looks like the following.

```
var myDataset = {
    "classes": [
        [{
            "name": "ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lecture",
            "days": "MWF",
            "times": "02:00 pm - 03:20 pm",
            "crn": "11215"
        }, {
            "name": "ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lab",
            "days": "W",
            "times": "09:00 am - 10:50 am",
            "crn": "11216"
        }],
        [{
            "name": "ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lecture",
            "days": "MWF",
            "times": "02:00 pm - 03:20 pm",
            "crn": "11215"
        }, {
            "name": "ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lab",
            "days": "F",
            "times": "02:00 pm - 03:50 pm",
            "crn": "11217"
        },
        {
        "name": "SOC 101 Introduction to Sociology Lecture",
        "days": "TBD",
        "times": "",
        "crn": "11044",
        "campus": "Online",
        "enrollment": "CLOSED",
        "short_name": "SOC 101 Lecture"
        }
        ]
    ]
};
```

In real world code, the `myDataset` object is updated dynamically through AJAX calls.

The data is updated through an API I wrote that offers filtering of results, so the user can set parameters to update the calendar view (which changes the `myDataset`).

One issue I have is, when I set a filter so that `myDataset` is empty, and then unfilter everything so that `myDataset` has data again, my FullCalendar view would simply be blank, even though there is data inside, and the events are being pushed (I've checked).

The problem seems to stem from the `removeEvents` method which is called every time the calendar needs new events rendered, replacing the old events:

```
        // Clear all events to prepare for the next set of events.
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

        // Add events from JSON data
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',
            function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                var events = [];
                var overlap = [];
                ....
```

I tried switching this method out with:

```
        // Clear all events to prepare for the next set of events.
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

However, that simply paints the events over existing events, so the result is a bunch of overlapping events overlayed each other.

I've tried `refetchEvents` and a number of others. I'm actually not even sure if it has anything to do with `removeEvents`.

My question is - how do I solve this issue? I apologize if the issue isn't as detailed as it should be, but I'm really lost at how to solve the issue of why no events are being rendered. The results I've shown above are as detailed as I could technically go to show how I debugged everything.

EDIT: Ok, so `rerenderEvents` gets rid of the issue. The only issue with `rerenderEvents` is that the events get displayed on TOP of previous events [when toggling between several arrays of events].

Comment: how do we recreate this issue in jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't know, since updating `myDataset` requires calling my API which isn't open =/ Re-running it doesn't emulate the issue, because obviously, you're reloading everything.

Comment: I used the fullcalendar jquery plugin to build a scheduler for my company. I have to say that the lack of a method to update events was very annoying. My way of solving this was deleting events then adding them back in with $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventObject, true);

Comment: yeah. you're right. how about `.fullCalendar('destroy');`

Comment: @Sushil Having `destroy` before `addEventSource` would simply have the calendar not show =P

Comment: oh you obviously need to call `.fullCalendar();` after destroy. ;)

Comment: Yep, that's what I did: http://puu.sh/jQZOK/fcd235168e.png

Comment: @JordanLittell While I am not updating events, the documentation is a bit ambiguous as to what the redraw events mean.

Comment: you should be calling the `destroy` before you update your dataset.

Comment: @Sushil Wow, that did it! You don't know how frustrated I was with this issue! Thank you again @Sushil!

Comment: @Sushil I don't know what I will do without you

Comment: dont worry. .there are many more better people out there ;)

Comment: @Sushil could you post the answer? I wrote the template below. Once you post it I'll delete it.

Comment: done. posted my answer :)

Comment: Accepted. Thank you again!

Comment: you're most welcome. please upvote it as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `destroy` your calendar before `re-initializing` it again.
To do that you can call `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');`

Set your `dataset` after you call the `destroy` event

```
var myDataset = result;
```

and finally initialize your calendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({...
```