# How do I Refetch FullCalendar only when a change actually occurs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, setinterval

I'm building a basic app which involves a FullCalendar.js calendar that's pulling data from Google Calendar. I can use setInterval and run fullCalendar's refetch function but it reloads all of the events.

```
setInterval(function(){$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')},40000)
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to get it to only update the events that were updated, or at the very least only redraw the events when an event is added/updated/deleted.

How would I do this?

Comment: You will have to use WebSockets to allow the server to push content to your app. If you are using .NET for your backend you can investigate SignalR http://signalr.net/

Comment: well I was more thinking of keeping things simple, simply polling Google every few minutes for changes, then updating if and only if the data received actually changes.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260969/fullcalendar-is-blank-when-having-to-be-redrawn-from-empty-data It seems that rerenderEvents can solve the problem. Is that what you want?